# jquery hide/show problem

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I know this is a really unelegent way of doing what I want, but it should work shouldnt it? if not what am i doing wrong please?!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#page2').click(function() {
    $('.page1').hide();
    $('.page3').hide();
    $('.page2').show();
    });
    $('#page1').click(function() {
    $('.page2').hide();
    $('.page3').hide();
    $('.page1').show();
    });
    $('#page3').click(function() {
    $('.page1').hide();
    $('.page2').hide();
    $('.page3').show();
    });
});
```

the html is

```
<a id="page1">page1</a>
<a id="page2">page2</a>
<a id="page3">page3</a>
<div class="page1">p1</div>
<div class="page2">p2</div>
<div class="page3">p3</div>
```

some of you may have noticed, this just isnt working as its meant to show the clicked element and hide the other shown ones, any help would be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Please replace "this just isnt working lol" with a complete description of what you expect the script to accomplish, and what exactly _does_ happen.

Comment: the problem is not in this part of the code ... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BCKh6/) ... maybe you need to load jQuery first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<a class="pageLink" data-page="page1">page1</a>
<a class="pageLink" data-page="page2">page2</a>
<a class="pageLink" data-page="page3">page3</a>
<div class="page" id="page1">p1</div>
<div class="page" id="page2">p2</div>
<div class="page" id="page3">p3</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    // hide all pages
    $(".page").hide();

    $(".pageLink").click(function() {
       // get the page id from the data attribute of the link
       var pageId = $(this).data("page");

       // hide all pages but the one we clicked
       $(".page[id!='"+pageId+"']").hide();

       // show the page we want
       $("#"+pageId).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KMhzy/

Comment: I actually ended up swapping to tis as it seems more efficient, however it again didnt work, HOWEVER I moved this snippet of code to the top of scripts.js and it actually worked, it seems something in the image slider code may have messed around with it! thankyou

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you place alert("Hello world"); in the ready event handler, does it work? Just to make sure that jQuery is working. Also check your console for any errors.

Second, you should probably have css where .page1, .page2, .page3 has display:none; so that they all start invisible.

Third, your `<a>` element needs the attribute src. Common way is to have hash (#) inside the src attribute so that the click handler does not take you anywhere.

Fourth, it should work? :-)

Comment: the console doesnt seem to be kicking out any errors, however the alert() isnt displaying either... even though i've a jquery image slider already working correctly!?

Comment: it seems the jquery slider code was messing with it! thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I would start by putting and ID to you're div

```
<div id="div_p1" class="page1">p1</div>
<div id="div_p2" class="page2">p2</div>
<div id="div_p3" class="page3">p3</div>
```

Second in you're CSS have you put the style `display:none` onto you're 3 different class?

And instead of hiding you `<a>` depending on what you are doing you should put them in the divs and just show/hide the divs?

Also, the $('.page2').hide(); should be done on a object like the div and not on a CSS class if I'm correct.  There for I would do

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#page2').click(function() {
    $('#div_p1').hide();
    $('#div_p3').hide();
    $('#div_p2').show();
    });
    $('#page1').click(function() {
    $('#div_p2').hide();
    $('#div_p3').hide();
    $('#div_p1').show();
    });
    $('#page3').click(function() {
    $('#div_p1').hide();
    $('#div_p2').hide();
    $('#div_p3').show();
    });
});

An easier way is to hide the controls `<a>` with a simple javascript method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('a').each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry i had included that in my css, i just hadnt posted it here! its now been sorted so thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Your anchor tags need an attribute `href="#"`. Also, call the click event for page1 to initialize the whole thing. Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/P25TX/

As an aside, you're reinventing the wheel here by essentially remaking what the jQuery UI Tabs control does. See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: All of what I said above assumes that jQuery is loaded and working, so pay attention to the other answers as well.

Comment: it had been loaded, but a previous script seemed to be messing with it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can do (if i understand what you want to do!):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('a').each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hxahZ/1/

Comment: thanks! I actually sorted it in a previous answer but thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#page2").click(function() {
        $('#page1a').hide();
        $('#page2a').hide();
        $('#page2a').show();
    });

    <a id="page1">page1</a>
    <a id="page2">page2</a>
    <a id="page3">page3</a>
    <div id="page1a" style="display:none">p1</div>
    <div id="page2a" style="display:none">p2</div>
    <div id="page3a" style="display:none">p3</div>
});
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to include the css, they are all set to display:none apart from page1 which is set to display:block;